# How to estimate parameters in trigram?

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods

A popular method of computing trigram in NLP is linear interpolation:

[image]

The question is how to estimate the three linear interpolation parameters to maximzie the following expression?
[image]

Any form of answer (e.g algorithms, explanations, and source code) is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Lagrange multiplier method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier); note that it is 'a necessary condition for optimality in constrained problems. Sufficient conditions for a minimum or maximum also exist.' However, you can simply choose global maximum among all found points.

Comment: yes, I misread it as a log of sum, but not sum of logs. See edited answer, pls

Comment: Thanks for your information, dude. What are the methods that can solve this problem programmatically?